# Android app won't work without "Use Shared Runtime"

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

When i am debugging, and the "Use Shared Runtime" Is ticked, everything works.
However, when i dare to untick it (For the purpose of archiving it), it no longer installs on the Visual Studio (Android 23-x68) emulator with a deployement error

`1>Build succeeded.
1>An error occured. See full exception on logs for more details.
1>Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS]`

I have already googled the issue, and it said to tick the supported architectures i intend to publish to. After i have done that however, nothing changed.
If i try to install it on a live device, the installation finishes correctly, however it crashes on startup. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default ABIs for a **`Debug`** configuration include all ABIs:

[image]

The default ABIs for a **`Release`** configuration include only Arm `v7a`:

[image]

Change your release configuration ABIs to match the ones that you wish to include in your archive.

Comment: I have already ticked them, namely every one of them. It still gives me the same error, on every emulator (both on the 86 and the 64 versions)

Comment: @CsabaKiss Select all the ABIs in the Release configuration, then Archive your project, Ad-hoc publish it, unzip the resulting `.apk` and verify that all the ABIs directories contain `libmonodroid.so`/`libmonosgen-2.0.so` and that there are x86 based directories.

Comment: I unzipped it, went to the lib folder, and only found armeabi-v7a. But i have ticked everything back at properties>android options>advanced>supported architectures. Exiting Visual Studio and going back, i found those boxes unticked again, and half of my android SDK missing. Any idea why did this happen?

Comment: @CsabaKiss You have to re-archive the project as an archive is a snapshot in time and changing project options after effects the ***next*** archive, not any of the existing ones.

Comment: I did, it just didn't saved the properties for one reason or an another, after several clicks on save. Now it works on the emulator, but not a live device. Any tools to debug a live phone?

Comment: @CsabaKiss Debug it on the device : https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/deployment,_testing,_and_metrics/debug-on-device/

Comment: I have already tried that, but it gives me the following errors:

-Mainactivity.cs: 'Resource.Layout' Does not contain definiton for 'Main'

However, the emulator once again works fine. And i do have a Main.axml under Resources>layout

Comment: Perfect answer, I swear you solve about 90% of my questions to google @SushiHangover

Comment: @BarneyChambers I greatly appreciate the comment, happy coding 